# Issue with Power bi date slicer

Tags: angular, azure, powerbi

I had an issue with Power bi date slicer.

Power bi date slicer calendar month/days are showing different language other English. it’s looks like Spanish language.

•   After Publish to (app.powerbi.com(dashboard) -  Report calendar looks fine month/days are showing in English language.

•   Local Power BI Desktop- Report calendar looks fine month/days are showing in English language.

But when the report is integrated with angular Application & deploy to azure. In Angular Reporting UI - In Power BI Report date slicer  calendar month/days are showing different language other English. it’s looks like Spanish language.
[See-attached-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJnBc.jpg)

Part of analysis:I had Verify

1. Power BI Desktop Regional Setting & Apply Language/ Model Language as English (United State)
2. https://app.powerbi.com Setting change Language setting from English to Default (Browser Language).
3. I had verified in my local computer is with regional settings English.

Non of the above is working for me .

Is there any way to change the language from Spanish to English language in Power bi date slicer calendar month/days?

Any suggestion on the Language issue is appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Did the above help your requirement

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct you are trying to embed the Power Bi in your angular application.

In the embed configuration you can mention, Language and Locale setting.

```
var embedConfig = {
    ...
    settings: {
        localeSettings: {
            language: "en",
            formatLocale: "en"
        }
    }
};
```

**Or**

You could add **&language=en** and **&formatlocale=en** parameters to the embed URL

```
https://powerbiembedurl&language=en&formatlocale=en
```

**Sample output**

When I changed the FormatLocale and Language to **en** and **es**.

[image]

[image]